# In Racket can I recursively process a syntax object like I would an s-expression?

Tags: recursion, racket, abstract-syntax-tree

Let's say I'm using s-expressions as an IR for a language I'm writing. Then I might have an AST that looks like

```
'(add (times (3 : int)
             (add (4 : int)
                  (5 : int)))
      (1 : int))
```

which I can process recursively without much trouble. For example, to erase type annotations I could do

```
(define (erase-types term)
  (match term
    [`(,val : ,type)
     val]
    [`(,binop ,arg1 ,arg2)
     `(,binop ,(erase-types arg1) ,(erase-types arg2))]))
```

---

Now suppose I wanted to do the same thing, but instead at compile time with a syntax object containing the same datum as the AST at the top. I tried to use some kind of pattern-based macro, but it seems that I can't use `(define-syntax erase-types-or-whatever ...)` in a recursive way.

I also tried putting a normal `match` function in a separate module with `(require (for-syntax ...))` and doing one big `syntax->datum` at the beginning, or even doing something like

```
(define (erase-types-or-whatever stx)
  (match (syntax-e stx)
    [...]))
```

but then I have `syntax->datum` everywhere and I have to restructure it again with `datum->syntax` and I don't really know how to use that (do I just put `#f` as the first argument?) and it all just feels like the absolute wrong way to do it.

What's the correct way to do this kind of syntax tree processing? The docs aren't super enlightening either when it comes to macros and syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#lang racket
(require syntax/parse)

(define-syntax : (λ (stx) (raise-syntax-error ': "used out of context" stx)))

(define (erase-types term)
  (syntax-parse term
    #:literals (:)
    [(val : type)      #'val]
    [(binop arg1 arg2) (with-syntax ([arg1 (erase-types #'arg1)]
                                     [arg2 (erase-types #'arg2)])
                         #'(binop arg1 arg2))]))

(erase-types #'(add (times (3 : int)
                           (add (4 : int)
                                (5 : int)))
                    (1 : int)))
```

Comment: I understand that we don't want `:` to be a pattern variable so it needs to be declared a literal. Does that mean the `(define-syntax : ...)` is just so `:` has a binding? Would it make a difference if I left that out and used `#:datum-literals (:)` instead? I tried it but I'm curious if I'm missing something with the `raise-syntax-error` part. Thanks for your help

Comment: Yes - that's just to provide a binding. You could use `#:datum-literals` but then you (or others) can't rename the identifier with `(provide (rename-out [: colon]))` . This could be useful if you need to use your `:` in code that uses `:` for something else.